# Is it possible to remove items from a array?

Tags: java, arrays

is it possible remove items from an array (not an arraylist)e.g.

```
JButton[] arr = {button1, button2, button3};
```

I want to remove button1 from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you could do: `arr[0] = null;`, and poof, button1 is gone *from the array*.

If you want the array to be smaller, say a 2 item array, then you'll need to do an array copy via `System.arraycopy(originalArray, 1, destinationArray, 0, 2)`, copying the last two items into a two-item array.

**The best solution:** just use a flippin' ArrayList as that's what it's built for.

Note as an aside, your question has nothing to do with Swing.

Answer (score 1):

After constructing an array, it's size is set, therefore you can't remove `button1` and change the array to `{button2, button3}`, but you can set the first item to `null` by doing `arr[0] = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ArrayUtils.removeElement(Object[],int)` from `org.apache.commons.lang`,it will delete the index `0` element and size of the array will be `decrease by 1`

```
arr =(JButton[])ArrayUtils.removeElement(arr , 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make any of your index `null`, but array size will remain same, that is how array's work right ?

A workaround would be to first convert your array into an ArrayList, remove item and then again make it an array -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
list.remove(button1);
array= list.toArray(array);
```